# d3 example of Stacked Bar Chart into jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsfiddle

I am referencing this d3 example of Stacked Bar Chart and try to implement in [jsfiddle](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)[1](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)

I want to add this example into `jsfiddle`, I have added 5 external source alone with source csv file but i got no output.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldenbutter/3a5Wk/)[2](http://jsfiddle.net/goldenbutter/3a5Wk/)

Can anyone help on this what I need to add there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have to embed the csv data in a different way, since it can neither be included into the fiddle like a js/css, nor requested from within javascript, because of [browser restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can for example [include it in the HTML part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231266/embedding-csv-in-html-for-use-with-d3-js) of the fiddle:

```
<pre id="csvdata">
  date,wounds,other,disease
  5/1854,0,95,105
  [...]
</pre>
```

I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a5Wk/1/), it is working now.

Comment: thanx a lot @ValarDohaeris its working..... one small request .... can I print all values on every stacked layout?