# replacing the anonymous function after embedding csv data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a basic d3 charge that pulls in data using `d3.csv` and then forwards it in an anonymous function like this

```
d3.csv("https://example.com/report.csv", function(error, data) {
console.log(data);

data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.zeit = parseDate(d.zeit);
        d.total = +d.total;
        d.count = d.count;
    });
...//code ommitted

});
```

However, since there's not a lot of data, I thought would embed the csv data using the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231266/embedding-csv-in-html-for-use-with-d3-js), which removes the anonymous function above. The log statement reveals an array of objects exactly the same as above, however when I do it this way, the chart doesn't display and I get an error that seems to arise from an array `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
  var raw = d3.select("#csvdata").text();
  var data = d3.csv.parse(raw);
  console.log(data)
  data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.zeit = parseDate(d.zeit);
            d.total = +d.total;
            d.count = d.count;
        });
 ...
```

Here is a fiddle for the first method [https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/5Y6kf/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/5Y6kf/1/) and here is a fiddle for the second one [not working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/cL3c8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding extraneous whitespace when you embed the data.  Instead of:

```
<pre id="csvdata">
    zeit,count,total,avg
    5:30,0,0,0
    6:00,14,41.1, $2.94 
    6:30,19,52, $2.74 
    7:00,21,74, $3.52 
    7:30,28,143.25, $5.12 
    8:00,30,141.3, $4.71 
    8:30,32,124.28, $3.88 
    9:00,24,74.8, $3.12 
    9:30,47,172.35, $3.67 
    10:00,27,119.77, $4.44 
    10:30,40,210.44, $5.26 
    11:00,29,150.95, $5.21 
    11:30,14,80.3, $5.74 
</pre>
```

Try:

```
<pre id="csvdata">
zeit,count,total,avg
5:30,0,0,0
6:00,14,41.1, $2.94 
6:30,19,52, $2.74 
7:00,21,74, $3.52
7:30,28,143.25, $5.12 
8:00,30,141.3, $4.71 
8:30,32,124.28, $3.88 
9:00,24,74.8, $3.12 
9:30,47,172.35, $3.67 
10:00,27,119.77, $4.44 
10:30,40,210.44, $5.26 
11:00,29,150.95, $5.21 
11:30,14,80.3, $5.74 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having comes from the indentation of your CSV data in `<pre id="csvdata">`.  Because you have indention, the header is being parsed as `"  zeit"`, instead of `"zeit"`. The same is true for each time in the first column. Here's my console's output of an example object produced when parsing your current data:

[image: example object]

This causes a problem when you try to access the `zeit` attribute of your objects on this line:

```
d.zeit = parseDate(d.zeit); // current place your code breaks
```

If you remove the indentation in `<pre id="csvdata">`, however, `zeit` is parsed correctly and you get a graph like this:

[image: graph]

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdml/v2Dbk/).

---

Note that even after fixing the indentation issue, you still have an error in your code:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: padding is not defined