# How to conditionally fill the area in radial chart correctly in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can calculate the negative and positive area. However, there are some unexpected gaps in my plot. [image]

Red line represents the 24 hour measurements of VALUE1 column and green line represents VALUE2 column. If VALUE1 is bigger than VALUE2, I want to fill the area with darkblue, else with lightblue. However, I ended up having some gaps  and my code partially works. How can I solve this issue? Does the problem lie where I code negative and positive area?

I expect to have a radial chart where if VALUE1 is bigger than VALUE2, I want to fill the area between two lines with darkblue color. IF VALUE2 is bigger than VALUE1, I want to fill the area between two lines with lightblue color. How can I achieve it?

Here is my *JSFiddle* link: https://jsfiddle.net/phvzur7a/
This is the part that does not work. I aim to fill area of crossing oints, but this part of code does not function at all.

```
function findCrossingPoints(data) {
  const crossingPoints = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const d1 = data[i - 1];
    const d2 = data[i];

    if ((d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2) * (d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) < 0) {
      // There's a crossing point between the two data points
      const t =
        (0 - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2)) /
        (d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2 - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2));
      const crossingValue1 = d1.VALUE1 + t * (d2.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE1);
      const crossingValue2 = d1.VALUE2 + t * (d2.VALUE2 - d1.VALUE2);
      crossingPoints.push({ VALUE1: crossingValue1, VALUE2: crossingValue2 });
    }
  }

  return crossingPoints;
}

const crossingPoints = findCrossingPoints(rawdata2);
```

```js
    const rawdata = [
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 160,
    "VALUE2": 110,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 0
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 102,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 20
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 153,
    "VALUE2": 117,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 40
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 117,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 60
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 95,
    "VALUE2": 103,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 80
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 157,
    "VALUE2": 119,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 100
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 129,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 120
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T01:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 135,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 140
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T01:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 126,
    "VALUE2": 119,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 160
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 121,
    "VALUE2": 110,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 180
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 133,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 200
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T02:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 124,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 220
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 121,
    "VALUE2": 112,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 240
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 147,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 260
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 98,
    "VALUE2": 102,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 280
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 136,
    "VALUE2": 109,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 300
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T04:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 130,
    "VALUE2": 112,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 320
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T04:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 156,
    "VALUE2": 100,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 340
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T05:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 135,
    "VALUE2": 102,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 360
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T05:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 380
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T05:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 116,
    "VALUE2": 103,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 400
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 129,
    "VALUE2": 107,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 420
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 107,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 440
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 460
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T07:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 116,
    "VALUE2": 113,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 480
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T07:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 92,
    "VALUE2": 109,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 500
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T07:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 92,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 520
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 540
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 126,
    "VALUE2": 105,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 560
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 135,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 580
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T09:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 108,
    "VALUE2": 115,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 640
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T10:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 114,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 700
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T11:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 107,
    "VALUE2": 114,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 760
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T12:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 110,
    "VALUE2": 115,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 820
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T13:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 101,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 880
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T14:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 145,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 940
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T15:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 100,
    "VALUE2": 107,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1000
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T16:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 155,
    "VALUE2": 107,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1060
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T17:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 132,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1120
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T18:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 110,
    "VALUE2": 112,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1180
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T19:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 160,
    "VALUE2": 119,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1240
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T20:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 127,
    "VALUE2": 104,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1300
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T21:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 150,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1360
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T22:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 108,
    "VALUE2": 111,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1420
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T22:59:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 151,
    "VALUE2": 102,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1439
  }
];

const width = 954;
const height = width;
const margin = 10;
const innerRadius = width / 5;
const outerRadius = width / 2 - margin;


    
      let rawdata2 = rawdata.filter(d => d.INSPECTION == 1);

      const minuteScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1439]) // 0 to 23:59 (24 hours * 60 minutes without -1 or else change to 1439 //- 1)
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

      const minuteTimeValues = rawdata2.map(d => d.minuteTime);

      const x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([0, 1439]) // Set the domain using the extent of the "minuteTime" values
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]); // Set the desired range

      console.log(rawdata)

      const minValue1 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
      const minValue2 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);
      const maxValue1 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
      const maxValue2 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);

      const yMin = minValue1 < minValue2 ? minValue1 : minValue2;
      const yMax = maxValue1 > maxValue2 ? maxValue1 : maxValue2;

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([yMin, yMax])
                  .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

// Modify the xAxis generator to display only the hour and add padding

const xAxis = (g) => g
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .call((g) => g.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.range(0, 24)) // create an array of hour values
    .join("g")
      .each((d, i) => d.id = `hour-${i}`)
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
          .attr("d", (d) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), innerRadius)}
            L${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), outerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("id", (d) => `hour-${d}`)
          .datum((d) => [d * 60, (d + 1) * 60])
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("d", ([a, b]) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(a), innerRadius-10)}
            A${innerRadius},${innerRadius} 0,0,1 ${d3.pointRadial(x(b), innerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("text")
        .append("textPath")
          .attr("startOffset", 6)
          .attr("href", (d) => `#hour-${d}`)
          .text((d) => d.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
          .attr("transform", (d) => {
            const angle = x(d * 60);
            const radius = innerRadius - 20; // reduce the radius to move the labels closer to the center
                        return `translate(${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), radius)})`;
          })
      )
  );



      const yAxis = g => g
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", 10)
        .call(g => g.selectAll("g")
          .data(y.ticks().reverse())
          .join("g")
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .call(g => g.append("circle")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
            .attr("r", y))
          .call(g => g.append("text")
            .attr("y", d => -y(d))
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .attr("stroke", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke-width", 5)
            .text((x, i) => `${x.toFixed(0)}${i ? "" : ""}`)
          .clone(true)
            .attr("y", d => y(d))
          .selectAll(function() { return [this, this.previousSibling]; })
          .clone(true)
            .attr("fill", "currentColor")
            .attr("stroke", "none")));

      const line = d3.lineRadial()
                    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
                    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime));

      const area = d3.areaRadial()
                    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
                    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime))

      const svg = d3.create("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round");

      svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("d", line
          .radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
          (rawdata2));

      svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "green")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("d", line
          .radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
          (rawdata2));
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ calc crossing points ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function findCrossingPoints(data) {
  const crossingPoints = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const d1 = data[i - 1];
    const d2 = data[i];

    if ((d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2) * (d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) < 0) {
      // There's a crossing point between the two data points
      const t = (0 - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2)) / ((d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2));
      const crossingValue1 = d1.VALUE1 + t * (d2.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE1);
      const crossingValue2 = d1.VALUE2 + t * (d2.VALUE2 - d1.VALUE2);
      crossingPoints.push({ VALUE1: crossingValue1, VALUE2: crossingValue2 });
    }
  }

  return crossingPoints;
}

const crossingPoints = findCrossingPoints(rawdata2);







// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



// separate data in positive and negative value
let separated = rawdata2.reduce((a, b,index) => {
    let sub = b.VALUE1 - b.VALUE2;
    if (sub > 0) {
        return {positive: [...a.positive, {...b,index}], negative: [...a.negative]};
    }
    return {positive: [...a.positive], negative: [...a.negative, {...b,index}]};

}, {positive: [], negative: []})

const positiveSets = [];

let previous = undefined

separated.positive.forEach((e)=>{
    //if not contiguous
    if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
        // create a new set
        positiveSets.push([e]);
    } else {
        // append value to previous set
        positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1] = [...positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1], e]
    }
    previous = e;
})
//same for negatives
const negativeSets = [];
previous = undefined
separated.negative.forEach((e)=>{
    if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
        negativeSets.push([e]);
    } else {
        negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1] = [...negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1], e]
    }
    previous = e;
})

const posG = svg.selectAll('.positive').data(positiveSets)
posG.enter().append('path')
    .attr('class','positive')
    .attr('fill','darkblue') // "positive" color
    .attr("d", (d)=>area
        .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
        .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
        (d));

const negG = svg.selectAll('.negative').data(negativeSets)
negG.enter().append('path')
    .attr('class','negative') // "negative" color
    .attr('fill','lightblue')
    .attr("d", (d)=>area
        .innerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
        .outerRadius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
        (d));

      svg.append("g")
        .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
        .call(yAxis);

      // console.log(negG)

      const container = d3.select("body").append("div");
      container.node().appendChild(svg.node());
```

```css
#csvdata {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` and make a [mcve] with the data inline somehting like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231266/embedding-csv-in-html-for-use-with-d3-js

Comment: @mplungjan I edited my code and included JS and CSV file in JsFiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const rawdata = [{
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 160,
    "VALUE2": 110,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 0
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 102,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 20
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 153,
    "VALUE2": 117,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 40
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 117,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 60
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 95,
    "VALUE2": 103,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 80
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 157,
    "VALUE2": 119,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 100
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 129,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 120
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T01:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 135,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 140
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T01:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 126,
    "VALUE2": 119,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 160
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 121,
    "VALUE2": 110,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 180
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 133,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 200
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T02:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 124,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 220
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 121,
    "VALUE2": 112,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 240
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 147,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 260
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 98,
    "VALUE2": 102,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 280
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 136,
    "VALUE2": 109,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 300
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T04:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 130,
    "VALUE2": 112,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 320
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T04:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 156,
    "VALUE2": 100,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 340
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T05:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 135,
    "VALUE2": 102,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 360
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T05:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 380
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T05:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 116,
    "VALUE2": 103,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 400
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 129,
    "VALUE2": 107,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 420
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 107,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 440
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 460
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T07:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 116,
    "VALUE2": 113,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 480
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T07:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 92,
    "VALUE2": 109,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 500
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T07:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 92,
    "VALUE2": 120,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 520
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 540
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:20:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 126,
    "VALUE2": 105,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 560
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 135,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 580
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T09:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 108,
    "VALUE2": 115,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 640
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T10:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 112,
    "VALUE2": 114,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 700
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T11:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 107,
    "VALUE2": 114,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 760
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T12:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 110,
    "VALUE2": 115,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 820
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T13:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 101,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 880
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T14:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 145,
    "VALUE2": 118,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 940
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T15:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 100,
    "VALUE2": 107,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1000
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T16:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 155,
    "VALUE2": 107,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1060
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T17:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 132,
    "VALUE2": 101,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1120
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T18:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 110,
    "VALUE2": 112,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1180
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T19:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 160,
    "VALUE2": 119,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1240
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T20:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 127,
    "VALUE2": 104,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1300
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T21:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 150,
    "VALUE2": 108,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1360
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T22:40:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 108,
    "VALUE2": 111,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1420
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T22:59:00.000Z",
    "VALUE1": 151,
    "VALUE2": 102,
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "minuteTime": 1439
  }
];

function checkLineIntersection(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY) {
  // if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contain the point
  var denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2, result = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    onLine1: false,
    onLine2: false
  };
  denominator = ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * (line1EndX - line1StartX)) - ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
  if (denominator === 0) {
    return result;
  }
  a = line1StartY - line2StartY;
  b = line1StartX - line2StartX;
  numerator1 = ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * a) - ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * b);
  numerator2 = ((line1EndX - line1StartX) * a) - ((line1EndY - line1StartY) * b);
  a = numerator1 / denominator;
  b = numerator2 / denominator;

  // if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
  result.x = line1StartX + (a * (line1EndX - line1StartX));
  result.y = line1StartY + (a * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
  /*
          // it is worth noting that this should be the same as:
          x = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndX - line2StartX));
          y = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndY - line2StartY));
          */
  // if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
  if (a > 0 && a < 1) {
    result.onLine1 = true;
  }
  // if line2 is a segment and line1 is infinite, they intersect if:
  if (b > 0 && b < 1) {
    result.onLine2 = true;
  }
  // if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true
  return result;
}
const width = 954;
const height = width;
const margin = 10;
const innerRadius = width / 5;
const outerRadius = width / 2 - margin;



let rawdata2 = rawdata.filter(d => d.INSPECTION == 1);

const minuteScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1439]) // 0 to 23:59 (24 hours * 60 minutes without -1 or else change to 1439 //- 1)
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

const minuteTimeValues = rawdata2.map(d => d.minuteTime);

const x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([0, 1439]) // Set the domain using the extent of the "minuteTime" values
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]); // Set the desired range

console.log(rawdata)

const minValue1 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
const minValue2 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);
const maxValue1 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
const maxValue2 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);

const yMin = minValue1 < minValue2 ? minValue1 : minValue2;
const yMax = maxValue1 > maxValue2 ? maxValue1 : maxValue2;

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([yMin, yMax])
  .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

// Modify the xAxis generator to display only the hour and add padding

const xAxis = (g) => g
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .call((g) => g.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.range(0, 24)) // create an array of hour values
    .join("g")
    .each((d, i) => d.id = `hour-${i}`)
    .call((g) => g.append("path")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
      .attr("d", (d) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), innerRadius)}
            L${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), outerRadius)}
          `))
    .call((g) => g.append("path")
      .attr("id", (d) => `hour-${d}`)
      .datum((d) => [d * 60, (d + 1) * 60])
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", ([a, b]) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(a), innerRadius-10)}
            A${innerRadius},${innerRadius} 0,0,1 ${d3.pointRadial(x(b), innerRadius)}
          `))
    .call((g) => g.append("text")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", 6)
      .attr("href", (d) => `#hour-${d}`)
      .text((d) => d.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .attr("transform", (d) => {
        const angle = x(d * 60);
        const radius = innerRadius - 20; // reduce the radius to move the labels closer to the center
        return `translate(${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), radius)})`;
      })
    )
  );



const yAxis = g => g
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .call(g => g.selectAll("g")
    .data(y.ticks().reverse())
    .join("g")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .call(g => g.append("circle")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
      .attr("r", y))
    .call(g => g.append("text")
      .attr("y", d => -y(d))
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 5)
      .text((x, i) => `${x.toFixed(0)}${i ? "" : ""}`)
      .clone(true)
      .attr("y", d => y(d))
      .selectAll(function() {
        return [this, this.previousSibling];
      })
      .clone(true)
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("stroke", "none")));

const line = d3.lineRadial()
  .curve(d3.curveLinear)
  .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime));

const area = d3.areaRadial()
  .curve(d3.curveLinear)
  .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime))

const svg = d3.create("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round");

svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("d", line
    .radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
    (rawdata2));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "green")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("d", line
    .radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
    (rawdata2));
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ calc crossing points ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function findCrossingPoints(data) {
  const crossingPoints = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const d1 = data[i - 1];
    const d2 = data[i];

    if ((d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2) * (d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) < 0) {
      // There's a crossing point between the two data points
      const t = (0 - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2)) / ((d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2));
      const crossingValue1 = d1.VALUE1 + t * (d2.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE1);
      const crossingValue2 = d1.VALUE2 + t * (d2.VALUE2 - d1.VALUE2);
      crossingPoints.push({
        VALUE1: crossingValue1,
        VALUE2: crossingValue2
      });
    }
  }

  return crossingPoints;
}

const crossingPoints = findCrossingPoints(rawdata2);

function getX(d) {
  return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[1]);
}

function getY(d) {
  return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[2]);
}

function getX2(d) {
  return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[1]);
}

function getY2(d) {
  return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[2]);
}






// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



// separate data in positive and negative value
let separated = rawdata2.reduce((a, b, index) => {
  let sub = b.VALUE1 - b.VALUE2;
  if (sub > 0) {
    return {
      positive: [...a.positive, { ...b,
        index
      }],
      negative: [...a.negative]
    };
  }
  return {
    positive: [...a.positive],
    negative: [...a.negative, { ...b,
      index
    }]
  };

}, {
  positive: [],
  negative: []
})

let positiveSets = [];

let previous = undefined

separated.positive.forEach((e) => {
  //if not contiguous
  if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
    // create a new set
    positiveSets.push([e]);
  } else {
    // append value to previous set
    positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1] = [...positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1], e]
  }
  previous = e;
})
//same for negatives
let negativeSets = [];
previous = undefined
separated.negative.forEach((e) => {
  if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
    negativeSets.push([e]);
  } else {
    negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1] = [...negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1], e]
  }
  previous = e;
})

negativeSets = negativeSets.map(s => {

  let first = s[0];
  let last = s[s.length - 1];
  let next;
  let prev;
  if (first.index > 0) {
    prev = rawdata2[first.index - 1]
  } else {

    prev = rawdata2[rawdata2.length - 1]
  }
  if (last.index === rawdata2.length - 1) {
    next = rawdata2[0];
  } else {
    next = rawdata2[last.index + 1];
  }


  let w = checkLineIntersection(getX(prev), getY(prev), getX(first), getY(first), getX2(prev), getY2(prev), getX2(first), getY2(first))
  let n = checkLineIntersection(getX(last), getY(last), getX(next), getY(next), getX2(last), getY2(last), getX2(next), getY2(next))

  return [{
    x1: w.x,
    y1: w.y,
    x2: w.x,
    y2: w.y
  }, ...s.map(w => ({
    x1: getX(w),
    y1: getY(w),
    x2: getX2(w),
    y2: getY2(w)
  })), {
    x1: n.x,
    y1: n.y,
    x2: n.x,
    y2: n.y
  }]

})

positiveSets = positiveSets.map(s => {

  let first = s[0];
  let last = s[s.length - 1];
  let next;
  let prev;
  if (first.index > 0) {
    prev = rawdata2[first.index - 1]
  } else {

    prev = rawdata2[rawdata2.length - 1]
  }
  if (last.index === rawdata2.length - 1) {
    next = rawdata2[0];
  } else {
    next = rawdata2[last.index + 1];
  }


  let w = checkLineIntersection(getX(prev), getY(prev), getX(first), getY(first), getX2(prev), getY2(prev), getX2(first), getY2(first))
  let n = checkLineIntersection(getX(last), getY(last), getX(next), getY(next), getX2(last), getY2(last), getX2(next), getY2(next))

  return [{
    x1: w.x,
    y1: w.y,
    x2: w.x,
    y2: w.y
  }, ...s.map(w => ({
    x1: getX(w),
    y1: getY(w),
    x2: getX2(w),
    y2: getY2(w)
  })), {
    x1: n.x,
    y1: n.y,
    x2: n.x,
    y2: n.y
  }]

})
const negG = svg.selectAll('.negative').data(negativeSets)
negG.enter().append('path')
  .attr('class', 'negative') // "negative" color
  .attr('fill', 'lightblue')
  .attr("d", (d) => d3.area().x0(d => d.x1).x1(d => d.x2).y0(d => d.y1).y1(d => d.y2)(d));


const posG = svg.selectAll('.positive').data(positiveSets)
posG.enter().append('path')
  .attr('class', 'positive') // "negative" color
  .attr('fill', 'darkblue')
  .attr("d", (d) => d3.area().x0(d => d.x1).x1(d => d.x2).y0(d => d.y1).y1(d => d.y2)(d));


svg.append("g")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);



// console.log(negG)

const container = d3.select("body").append("div");
container.node().appendChild(svg.node());
```

```css
#csvdata {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qLykpsr9/)

`checkLineIntersection(...)` compute crossing point for given segment

yes, it took me 9 days to understand and do it:

What I did (in an awful manner), I calculated crossing point of every extremity of negative and positive set, created a new set of point for area and plotted those areas.

My first idea was to compute actual data entry of every crossing point, but I discovered that they do not match crossing point in polar coordinate.

I don't know if this is any use to you.

The only thing I learned is : You can't interpolate between two point in polar coordinate with straight lines.

Good luck

Comment: You got my upvote! But please prefer to add working code examples as embedded SO snippets. External linked examples - using services such as codepen, jsfiddle, codesandbox, stackblitz, etc. – are perfectly fine as additional illustrations of how the code actually works (and also nice to play around with a solution). However, external links may expire - you'll find a lot of older SO posts with dead links, which is a pity :(   I've included the example.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll do it from now on.